# Need to filter lpstat output for older than 4 days

Tags: shell, unix, awk

We have a requirement where we need to filter lpstat -o output which are older than 4 days. We need to accomplish this with a shell script or awk command. Appreciate your help if you can help us.

Example
The current date is 8th December we are the below output with lpstat -o command.

```
XXXX-CB05-2513315      xyzadm            5120   Sun 01 Dec 2022 12:23:22 AM UTC
YYYY-AR19-2519281      xyxadm            2048   Wed 02 Dec 2022 09:38:26 AM UTC
YYYY-BC19-2519281      xyxadm            2048   Wed 04 Dec 2022 09:38:26 AM UTC
ZZZZ-PU05-2520131      xyzadm            2048   Wed 07 Dec 2022 02:19:40 PM UTC
```

We need the end output

```
XXXX-CB05-2513315
YYYY-AR19-2519281
YYYY-BC19-2519281
```

Regards
Ravi Pandey

We tried using `awk` we are able to filter the Printer name we need the logic to compare the date and filter the output.

Comment: Edit your question and include your current `awk` attempts and the output/errors you saw.

Answer (score 0):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let output of `command` be

```
XXXX-CB05-2513315      xyzadm            5120   Sun 01 Dec 2022 12:23:22 AM UTC
YYYY-AR19-2519281      xyxadm            2048   Wed 02 Dec 2022 09:38:26 AM UTC
YYYY-BC19-2519281      xyxadm            2048   Wed 04 Dec 2022 09:38:26 AM UTC
ZZZZ-PU05-2520131      xyzadm            2048   Wed 07 Dec 2022 02:19:40 PM UTC
```

then

```
command | awk 'BEGIN{months["Jan"]="01";months["Feb"]="02";months["Mar"]="03";months["Apr"]="04";months["May"]="05";months["Jun"]="06";months["Jul"]="07";months["Aug"]="08";months["Sep"]="09";months["Oct"]="10";months["Nov"]="11";months["Dec"]="12";cutoff=strftime("%Y%m%d",systime()-345600)}($7 months[$6] $5)<=cutoff{print $1}'
```

gives (today) output

```
XXXX-CB05-2513315
YYYY-AR19-2519281
YYYY-BC19-2519281
```

Explanation: In `BEGIN` I create array `months` which I fill so I can use it to convert month in LETTERletterletter form to digitdigit form and compute cutoff value - or what day was 4th days ago, for which I leverage [Time Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Time-Functions.html), I take current time in seconds since starts of epoch and then subtract 345600 from it, as 4 days = 345600 seconds (`4*24*60*60`), I normalize dates to YYYYMMDD dates - using `strftime` (in `BEGIN`) and taking and processing column (for each row). Observe choice of format date is choice (not some whim) as in YYYYMMDD units are order from biggest to lowest: year, month, day and thus they might be compared as number of string giving expected results. For each row where day is equal or lower (i.e. same or earlier) than `cutoff` I `print` first column (`$1`).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thanks a ton sir this exactly what i am looking for tested its working as expected